# Attemptimg to use a predicate function causes the error: 'std::sort' no matching overloaded function found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std

I'm attempting to use the `std::sort()` algorithm with a custom predicate, but I'm getting a compiler error. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with C++17 and the v142 toolset.

I'm copying the exact code from the [Microsoft Documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/algorithm-functions?view=vs-2019#sort). The code is below:

## Predicate Function:

```
bool UDgreater ( int elem1, int elem2 )
{
    return elem1 > elem2;
}
```

## main:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    v1.push_back(2 * i + 1);
}

std::sort( v1.begin( ), v1.end( ), UDgreater );
```

## Error:

The `std::sort()` line hits an error for the predicate function itself:

> 'UDgreater' non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

No other code exists within my test project, besides the inclusion of `<algorithm>` and `<vector>`.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change UDgreater as below:

```
struct {
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const
    {   
         return a > b;
     }   
 } UDgreater;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells us that your `UDgreater()` is NOT a free-standing function, but rather it is a **non-static class method** (an important detail you did not mention).

As a non-static class method, it cannot be used *DIRECTLY* as a predicate for standard algorithms.  You would have to wrap it using either a functor (pre C++11) or a lambda (C++11 and later), eg:

```
// using a functor...

struct UDgreaterFunctor
{
    YourClassType &myClass;

    UDgreaterFunctor(YourClassType &aMyClass) : myClass(aMyClass) {}

    bool operator()(int elem1, int elem2) const {
        return myClass.UDgreater(elem1, elem2);
    }
};

std::sort( v1.begin(), v1.end(), UDgreaterFunctor(*this) );
```

```
// using a lambda...

std::sort( v1.begin(), v1.end(),
    [this](int elem1, int elem2){
        return this->UDgreater(elem1, elem2);
    }
);
```

Comment: As the comparison does not use `this`, there is no point to forward the call to the class or the lambda.

Comment: Thank you very much! I foolishly forgot to mention that I had a header file with the definitions, recreating its usage in my actual project. Luckily I'm able to simply move the function, but these alternative methods are absolutely useful. Thank you all for your help, I'll learn from this to ask better questions.

Comment: Really strange behavior that you edited out the "thank you very much" at the end of my question. Why not remove the ending question as well, considering it's also implied? Not sure why you'd do that and make my question seem much colder than intended.

Comment: @trainingmode because this is a Q&A site. Posts need actual questions, not implied questions. As for the "thank you", see posts like [Why is saying "Thank you!" in question undesirable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115694/) and [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/)

Comment: @trainingmode you are not supposed to comment with thanks on every answer. You show thanks by up voting things that help you, and marking answers as accepted that help you solve your issues.